# How to handle AVPlayer when device changes orientation?

Tags: objective-c, landscape-portrait, screen-rotation, avplayerviewcontroller, avplayerview

My app only supports portrait orientation. But I have used AVPlayerViewController in one screen. App has UINavigationViewController and UITabBarViewController. When device is rotated to landscape mode during video play, I am having hard time to change its frame?

How can I achieve this? Where should I change frame of AVPlayerView?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSNumber *val = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:val forKey:@"orientation"];
```

Or ask the visible View Controller :

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    return self.CurrentViewController.preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return self.CurrentViewController.shouldAutorotate;
}
```

Comment: Do I need to change frame of AVPlayerView after applying this code?

Comment: First check without changing frame...if not working then I think you have to reset the layer's frame, and re-add it to the view